# How to stop terminal rotating icon in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running a npm script that watches for changes and recompiles my files.

With one of the latest update, when I run this script, VSC shows in the terminal window a rotating icon signalling something is running. Good in general, but extremely distracting if the task is constantly running like in this case.

It is there any option to remove or hide this status message?
Thanks!

VSC Version: 1.57.1 (system setup)
Commit: 507ce72a4466fbb27b715c3722558bb15afa9f48
Date: 2021-06-17T13:28:07.755Z
Electron: 12.0.7
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043

[image: Terminal taskbar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In vscode v1.59 there is a setting to disable that spinning icon animation:

The new setting `terminal.integrated.tabs.enableAnimation` will disable animation in the terminal tab icon.  For tasks instead of a spinner the play button will be used:

[image: no animation terminal tab]

Comment: This setting solved my problem and I could re-enable the new `"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true` set.

Answer (score 2):

I found that to return to the previous terminal behavior, I need to add the `"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": false` setting. Maybe it is an overkill, but solved my problem.